# Deploying Remix App to Lambda Function in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, remix.run, esbuild

I'm in the process of deploying a remix.run application to a lambda function in AWS. I was able to hack my way through the process and have it working, but there are a couple steps I don't understand.

I'm combining into one question since I believe the issues are related, but happy to post into separate questions.

1. **esbuild technically has to run twice:**  Remix uses esbuild when `npm run build` is called - this is the first instance of esbuild. However, if I deploy that output file to the lambda function, I receive an error. I can resolve that error by running esbuild on that output file, zipping it and deploying it to lambda.  Why does esbuild need to run twice?

   The lambda function expects a certain format (e.g. `exports.handler = async (event, context) => { ... }`), but I should have already resolved this by configuring Remix to use `createRequestHandler` from `@remix-run/architect`.
2. **esbuild complains about not being able to resolve dependencies on `aws-sdk` packages:** The code runs fine when running on the dev server so everything should be installed correctly. The fix is easy, mark all the `aws-sdk` packages as external, which is the right thing to do anyways since it's included in the lambda runtime. But, I'm confused why it throws the error?

Any insight would be much appreciated.